# In acumatica, how can I make changes in the Cost tab show up in the Revenue tab?

Tags: acumatica

For example, if I change the "Original Budgeted Quantity" field to 9.00 (see first image below), I would like that to also change in the Revenue tab (see second image) without having to change the same thing twice.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

**Cost Tab**

[image: Cost Tab]

**Revenue Tab**

[image: Revenue Tab]

Here are the details of the two fields I have highlighted in the images above:

**Cost Tab Field**

[image: Cost Tab Field]

**Revenue Tab Field**

[image: Revenue Tab Field]

Let me know if I need to clarify anything or provide more information :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with the Project Entry screen, and after a quick glance I couldn't find an easy way to tie the records from the Cost Budget tab to the Revenue Budget tab.

If you are planning on tying these two records together you may need some additional customization work to create the link that you are looking for if it doesn't already exist.

As far as the update itself, that is pretty straightforward and can be accomplished with a simple event handler, as demonstrated below.

```
namespace MyCompany.MyCustomization
{
    public class ProjectEntryExtMyCustomization : PXGraphExtension<ProjectEntry>
    {
        public static bool IsActive() => true;

        #region Actions
        #endregion
        #region Events

        protected virtual void _(Events.FieldUpdated<PMCostBudget, PMCostBudget.qty> eventHandler)
        {
            PMCostBudget row = eventHandler.Row;
            if (row is null) return;

            // Replace the stub below with your PMRevenueBudget lookup
            // using the link that you have defined.
            PMRevenueBudget revenueDetail = new PMRevenueBudget();

            // Assigns the PMRevenueBudget Qty field to match the PMCostBudget new value.
            revenueDetail.Qty = eventHandler.NewValue as decimal?;

            // Updates the PMRevenueBudget record in the cache.
            Base.RevenueBudget.Update(revenueDetail);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Don't forget to replace the line where I create a new PMRevenueBudget with the logic that you need for looking up the linked PMRevenueBudget record that you need. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks for that @Sean! I noticed it only works for the first row of the grid, so if I had a few rows, would I be right to assume that the RowSelected event would allow me to update a specific row?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the first row of the grid, is that on the PMCostBudget grid it only recognizes when you update the first record? I would check that the grid has the SyncPosition flag and that the Qty field has CommitChanges = true.

Comment: Yeah that's right, the PMCostBudget grid. I should probably mention that I haven't yet created a link between the two fields yet and replaced the stub. I found a post online about linking fields together: 

https://www.augforums.com/forums/postid/108/

Is this what you meant by creating a link between the two fields?